# Removing changed pixels in land use time series (MCD12Q1) using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, land-use

I have 20 rasters of my study area land use which is from MCD12Q1.

I want to remove the changed pixels in 20 years.

I tried to use ArcGIS Pro, but I could distinguish only two rasters with raster calculation using "a"-"b". If the result is 0 ,it means that this pixel is not changed.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Con (Range == 0, R1) where Range is output of Cell satistics

Comment: Thanks a lot for you! That's brilliant!